# Confused about reported kernel CVE by openscap with OVAL on ubuntu 20.04/22.04 - false positive?

Tags: kernel, vulnerability

I use extensively openscap with OVAL definitions provided by Canonical for a year now (https://security-metadata.canonical.com/oval/) .

It works well, but I am confused about some results regarding a few CVEs related to kernels, for Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.

Let take the example of CVE-2022-43945 : https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-43945
The kernel version patching this CVE is 5.15.0-56.62 for Ubuntu 22.04.

On this machine, everything is up to date :

```
fjc@nas:~$ apt list --upgradable
En train de lister... Fait
fjc@nas:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
fjc@nas:~$ uname -a
Linux nas 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I run openscap against latest OVAL definition :

```
fjc@nas:~$ wget -O com.ubuntu.$(lsb_release -cs).cve.oval.xml.bz2  https://security-metadata.canonical.com/oval/com.ubuntu.$(lsb_release -cs).cve.oval.xml.bz2
--2022-12-10 17:47:11--  https://security-metadata.canonical.com/oval/com.ubuntu.jammy.cve.oval.xml.bz2
Resolving security-metadata.canonical.com (security-metadata.canonical.com)... 185.125.190.29, 185.125.190.20, 185.125.190.21, ...
Connecting to security-metadata.canonical.com (security-metadata.canonical.com)|185.125.190.29|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2121903 (2,0M) [application/x-bzip2]
Saving to: ‘com.ubuntu.jammy.cve.oval.xml.bz2’

com.ubuntu.jammy.cve.oval.xml.bz2                              100%[====================================================================================================================================================>]   2,02M   658KB/s    in 3,1s

2022-12-10 17:47:15 (658 KB/s) - ‘com.ubuntu.jammy.cve.oval.xml.bz2’ saved [2121903/2121903]

fjc@nas:~$ bunzip2 -f com.ubuntu.$(lsb_release -cs).cve.oval.xml.bz2
fjc@nas:~$ oscap oval eval --report report_cve_$(hostname).html com.ubuntu.$(lsb_release -cs).cve.oval.xml | grep 202243945
Definition oval:com.ubuntu.jammy:def:2022439450000000: true
```

And the result is true for CVE-2022-43945 !

It looks like a false positive to me, am I right ? Is it an error in the OVAL definitions, or is it deliberate because the CVE may not be fully eliminated even if the right kernel version is used ?
I noticed this for a few months for some kernel related CVEs. (If I remember correctly, I never experienced this behaviour with 18.04)

Comment: I reached a member of the Ubuntu Security Team. He confirmed it was a kind of false positive specifically on my 22.04 machine (not reproducible on all machines). He updated the OVAL definitions to check it correctly.